# Use VolatileAssembly directive without installing the T4 Toolbox

Tags: t4, t4-toolbox

I'd like to use `VolatileAssembly` from the T4 Toolbox but do not want to require all developers to install the T4 Toolbox.

Is it possible include the DLL with with project in source control and reference it by path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 you are able to do:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)\external\SomeAssembly.dll"#>
```

Which I believe is what you are asking for.

EDIT: I understand VolatileAssembly is used to reference assemblies without locking them. This is one of the fixes for VS2010 SP1 so if your devs run VS2010 SP1 you shouldn't need VolatileAssembly anymore.

Comment: Thanks @FuleSnabel. I tried adding this before the VolitileAssembly directive without success. The error is "A processor named 'T4Toolbox.VolitileAssemblyProcessor' could not be found for the directive named 'VolitileAssembly'.

Comment: Ahh I see, well it seems this is slightly more complicated than my initial assumption. Do you mind posting a template using the VolatileAssembly in a way similar to how you like to use. I could then experiment a bit. Also have you tried asking this question at: http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/?

Comment: Maybe this link on how to deploy custom directive processors can be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138364.aspx

Comment: Thanks, saw your edit. With VS2010 SP1 you no longer need VolitileAssembly from T4Toolbox.